# Telegram бот с потоком

Tags: python, многопоточность, telegram-bot

Бот раз в пол часа должен проверять базу данных, автоматически. На JAVA я писал потоки и все работало как надо. Сейчас пишу на Python и столкнулся с проблемой что поток вообще не запускается, либо работает поток а бот нет, либо на оборот. Как можно исправить?

```
import threading
import time
from datetime import datetime

import telebot

from DataBase import DataBase
from Geners import Geners
from KeyButtons import KeyButtons

bot = telebot.TeleBot("токен", threaded=True)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def handle_text(message):
    buttons = KeyButtons()       # geting keyboards
    database = DataBase()        # db
    from Results import Results  # get results

    chat_id = message.from_user.id
    username = message.chat.username
    first_name = message.from_user.first_name

    database.connect()

    print(username + " : " + message.text)

    database.close()


def sending():  # рассылка
    from Results import Results
    database = DataBase()
    date = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

    while True:
        if not database.connect():
            database.connect()
        print("+")
        Results().sendSending(date)
        database.close()
        time.sleep(60)  # sec
        date = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)  # infinity loop
    my_thread = threading.Thread(target=sending())
    my_thread.start()
```

Comment: Просто повесте на ваш чекер cron, в чем проблема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```java
bot.polling(none_stop=True)  # infinity loop
```

Здесь даже комментарий написан, что это бесконечный цикл, следовательно эти строки

```java
my_thread = threading.Thread(target=sending)
my_thread.start()
```

не выполнятся

Попробуйте сначала запустить поток, а потом бота

Comment: Только нужно ссылку на функцию поместить, а не ее результат: `threading.Thread(target=sending)` :)

Comment: @gil9red исправил)